# python ftplib upload binary file

Tags: python, ftplib

I use python ftplib to upload binary file to remote ftp server, but it always transfers less than its actually size.
ps: local env is windows, remote server is linux.
I use:

```
    'ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % filename,open(filename,'rb'))'
```

I think python's api read() is not work properly, it recognizes some special character as EOF which actually not.

How can I upload a binary file without lost bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several hard tests have been made before I understood why. First, this is not a bug in python. Because the file to be transferred hasn't been flushed to disk from memory,for this:

```
f.retrbinary('RETR '+filename, filehandler.write, bufsize)
```

After doing this, file handler is not closed explicitly, `retrbinary`doesn't close it, so storing it immediately will lose some bytes which are in memory.
So if we close the file handler explicitly after storing it, like this:

```
f.retrbinary('RETR '+filename, filehandler.write, bufsize)
filehandler.close()
```

then we got all bytes, for more detail, see: 'http://blog.csdn.net/hongchangfirst'

Comment: a more detailed answer would be helpful! the link you offered i can not understand because i can't read chinese/mandarin/whatever text..

Comment: Hey i want to describe what my solution was, because the accepted answer doesn't solved my problem but was moving me in the right direction:

I ran out of ideas and can not invest more time. So i split up my python script into two scripts: first script generates the file, second script only does the ftp upload. Now it works - but i know it doesn't solve the problems origin...

Comment: I did it slightly different way: one method which writes to the file and which is a callback for the f.retrbinary()

Answer (score 2):

I actually just fought through this issue. I had to close the file that was being written before I opened it to upload to the FTP server.

```
out2 = open('file.csv')
for r1 in cursor:
    out2.write(str(r1))
out2.close()

ftp_census = file_loc
stor_census = str("STOR egocensus_" + demoFileDate + ".csv")
fc = open(ftp_census, 'rb')
ftp.storbinary(stor_census, fc, 1024)
```

Once I closed the file the file size on the FTP server was correct. I also edited the original answer to show the code better. I probably could code this better but it is working....